# Disable authentication in postgres entirely

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I've installed postgres 10 under Ubuntu, and trying to perform an import from the command line like:

```
psql -f dump.sql -U postgres -d dbname
```

The operation fails with the message:

> psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

I read I should edit the `pg_hba.conf` file. The problem starts here, because I don't have any `pg_hba.conf` file on my system. The only similar file I have found is `/usr/share/postgresql/10/pg_hba.conf.sample` but it doesn't contain any code, just comments.

So what I did was create a `pg_hba.conf` in this same directory with the contents:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I also put the same into `pg_hba.conf.sample` (although I don't think this file is used anyhow but anyways..)

Then, I restarted the server with:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Nothing changed, I'm getting the same error.

Then, I tried all possible combinations `in pg_hba.conf`, from 'trust' to 'md5', 'localhost', 127.0.0.1, anything I could find on the internet. Even created new users and tried with those, also installed pgadmin to grant all access to all users to every database.... Restarted the OS, reinstalled postgres, tried everything again and again..

The problem still persist.

Anything else I could try? Is there a way to disable the authentication entirely?

It's meant to be a database for local testing purposes only, and I've been trying for three hours just to get it to work.

Comment: Did you remove the other lines that refers to security? It parses the rules in the order they appear in the file.

Comment: Yes, you **do** have a `pg_hba.conf`. It might just be in a non-default location. If you can connect as the superuser (`postgres`)  you can use `show hba_file;` to find the location of the file your server is using

Comment: @kometen I have nothing else in the file apart from these three lines.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I type `psql` in terminal, it says "role "tom" (my ubuntu username) does not exist". If I type `psql -U postgres`, it gives me the same  "peer authentication failed..." message. So how to connect as superuser?

Comment: If you have sudo rights the following probably will work `sudo su -c psql postgres`, on ubuntu I believe the config files are under `/etc/postgresql/10/main`.

Comment: The configuration file was indeed under `/etc/postgresql/10/main`. My bad, I wasn't looking enough. Thanks, I edited it and now it works.